# python: How can I print y as a function of x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a larger Code and for that i need to solve a small problem so i made a test script only consisting of that problem.

How can I change it that it prints
4
9
16
25
36
right now it prints
4
4
4
4
4

```
x = 2
y = x**2

for i in range(5):
    print(y)
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a function!

```
x = 2

def y(x):
    return x**2

for i in range(5):
    print(y(x))
    x += 1
```

If you want something more elaborate, more verbose, but a little bit unreadable (although in this case I'd recommend it because of how short the function is), you can also use a lambda:

```
y = lambda x: x**2
```

The statements are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap it in list comprehension

```
x = 2
[(x+i) ** 2 for i in range(5)]
[4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this.

> x=2
>
> def Square(x):
>
> > y=x**2
> >
> > print(y)
>
> for i in range(5):
>
> > Square(x)
> >
> > x+=1

You used mathematical equation, but make y as a global variable.
So if you want to insert a value and get a new result each time, you should define function(s) of your own. It is also good to use what has already been created.

I hope this helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be:

Define a function with two arguments. The down and upper limit of your list's range. Then return a list with those numbers squared.

```
def squared(start, upper):
    return [n**2 for n in range(start, upper)]

print squared(2, 10)
```

But if you just need a function to return a given input squared, then:

```
def squared(x):
    return x**2

print squared(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 2
for i in range(5):
   y = x**2
   print(y)
   x += 1
```

Explanation: you have calculated y at once only. Based on your requirement, the calculation should be done whenever x is changed. So added in a loop.